# How to make sure the token doesn't expire during fetching data?

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my code:

```
data = {"client_id": config.client_id, "client_secret": config.client_secret,
        "grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "PublicApi"}


def kAuth(self, data):
    urlAuth = 'http://...'
    try:
        response = requests.post(urlAuth, data=data, verify=False)
        return response
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print (err)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print (e)
        sys.exit(1)

def kData(self, data, auth_token,...):

    hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    urlApi = 'http://...'.format(apifolder,additional)
    responsedata = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
    if responsedata.ok:
        num_of_records = int(math.ceil(responsedata.json()['total']))
        if num_of_records == 0:
            print ("No new records to import.")
            return None

        ...


        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_workers) as executor:
            futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata, page, hed, data)) for page in pages]
            for data in as_completed(futh):
                datarALL.extend(data.result())
        print ("Finished generateing data.")
        return datarALL

def getdata(self, page, hed, data, ...):
   ...
   responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
   return  ...

response = my_lib.kAuth(data)
if response.ok:
    access_token = response.json()['access_token']
    token_type = response.json()['token_type']
    expires_in = response.json()['expires_in']
    response_k = my_lib.kData(data, access_token, apifolder)
```

I first perform authentication using the `kAuth` function. Then I make first get call to get the number of records to import, then I'm using threads to get the data (pages) using `self.getdata` function. when all threads finish I return the result. This works however there is a risk that the token will expire in the middle of the process.

My Question:
currently the code make authentication only once at the beginning then the `auth_token` is passed and used with in the `header`. How can I modify it to refresh the token if it expires ?

Comment: You refresh the token in time, there's an expiration information in it.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm aware of it.. the question is how to refresh it and let the code continue from where it stopped.

Comment: Hold the token globally and update it on time. Handing it over as argument will prevent you from updating it.

Comment: @KlausD. I used Erik answer and modified getdata to update the token and moved the hed to be a class variable. However getdata is executed by threads.. I'm afraid that this is not thread safe solution.

Comment: When you run several threads it will happen that the token expires in all threads at the same time and you will have many (or even all) threads refreshing the token at the same time. This is way I would use an extra threads that does nothing else then refreshing the token let's say a minute before it expires. An all threads rely on that token.

Comment: @KlausD. I get the idea of what you are saying but I don't see how I can implement it. When encountering 401 I basically need to make the thread wait until the refresh thread will finish and he needs to notify all others.. But another issue that rises here the refresh thread need also to be terminated with finishing retrieving all data... This complicate things.

Comment: Lets say `expires_in` is `3600`. When you run a simple thread that sleeps 3540 seconds and retrieves a new token in a loop. You will never get a 401 this way.

Comment: @KlausD. But i don't have control over the context switch. I don't know if this thread will get CPU time before the other threads. Also, still this thread wants to update a class variable while the other threads want to read it.  I get your idea but I don't see how the solution is thread safe.

Comment: It is, at least the GIL will not allow this kind of concurrent access. Also, when your thread does not get CPU resources in a minute you have other problems to solve than the token.

Comment: Is it exceptionally expensive to get a new token? If not, then just skip your concurrency worries and get a new token when you need it, in as few lines of code as possible. No need for fancy token-updater threads, locking, cross-thread coordination etc.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand not expensive at all and it unlikely to happen often. I'm just worried about thread safe issue. I'm not looking for fancy I'm looking for clean simple approach that will be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably be optimistic and just try the request. If it fails, then re-authenticate and then retry the request:

```
def getdata(self, page, hed, data, ...):
   ...
   responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
   if responsedata.status_code == 401:
      hed['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + my_lib.kAuth(kauth_data).json()['access_token']
      responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
   return  ...
```

Or, as Klaus D. suggests, check current time and refresh the token if `expires_in` has been reached.

Comment: I wanted to work with the expires_in but I'm not sure how. I thought maybe the library provide a way to handle it

Comment: Which library? `requests`? It doesn't know how to get a token from your API, and will not start a dormant thread that wakes up when `expires_in` is approaching.

Comment: You can rely on `expires_in`, but you'll still need to handle the case where your API decides to expire the token earlier than you anticipated.

Comment: I think it's better that the first thread that encounter expired token will refresh it for all of them. I changed the header to be a class variable so all threads access the same variable. The problem is how to make the access & update of this variable thread safe.

Comment: If you want thread safety, then require callers to acquire a Lock before accessing or changing the token. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock